# Why is the expiration of the refresh token not returned?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

When requesting access/refresh tokens the refresh token is sent, however the "refresh_token_expires_in" property is missing in the API response.  I have no idea what the offical expiration timestamp is. Why is the documented property missing?

I receive the same response body for both grant type "authorization_code" and "refresh_token" authorization requests.  Below is an example of what I receive.

```
{  
   "token_type": "Bearer",
   "expires_in": "3599",
   "scope": "Calendars.Read Calendars.ReadWrite Files.Read Files.ReadWrite User.Read User.Read.All",
   "expires_on": "1455797016",
   "not_before": "1455793116",
   "resource": "https://graph.microsoft.com/",
   "access_token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiL...",
   "refresh_token": "AAABAAAAiL9Kn2Z27Uub..."
}
```

As you can see only the access token expiration is included.  A bonus question is what is this "not_before"?  I cannot find reference to what this property means.

http://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/authorization/app_authorization
Renew expiring access token using refresh token
"The new expiration times are the number of seconds, specified in the expires_in and refresh_token_expires_in values, respectively, from the time when the token-refreshing request was submitted successfully."

The section, "Acquire an access token", even states: "In any production code, your app needs to watch for the expiration of these tokens and renew the expiring access token before the refresh token expires."  However, it does not seem to give this expiration that I should monitor.

There seems to be an open issue for this on getHub
https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/115

Comment: hmmm... on 18 Feb. 2016 20:48 CET siewmoi removed the "refresh_token_expires_in" from the documentation example.  Apparently the graphAPI documentation is altered to current behavior rather than treating it definition of what the user should expect.  The API documentation is still treated like the product is a beta.

Comment: Can you not just use the expires_on value of the access token to determine when to use the refresh token you've been given?  Ie if the access token only has (say) 5 minutes left to live, use the refresh token to get another one?

Comment: And how do you determine when this refresh token is not available to do this access token retrieval?  The problem I have is that I have a long process, and extensive Sync.  It is to run over-night, however if this refresh token dies during this process then this is potentially a problem.  Being able to detect that the token would not survive the process would allow one to warn prior to starting.  It appears however that refresh tokens might be updated when new access tokens are requested.  For me it is all moot, as I am looking to convert to user credential authentication flow.

Comment: Also, when we refresh we get a new refresh token - do subsequent refreshes get to live longer or do they expire at the same time regardless?

Comment: do you happen to know the format of the date  {"expires_on": "1455797016"} is that Iso?

Comment: it is a unix timestamp

Comment: determine when a refresh token expires is not possible. why? well that is open for debate. needless to say it's frustrating and painful ... but for some reason MS feels like they shouldn't tell developers. This makes things hard.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the expires when it's close or expired use the refresh tokens to request a new access token:

```
// Get current time + 5 minutes (to allow for time differences)
$now = time() + 300;
if ($token->expires <= $now) {
    // Token is expired (or very close to it) so let's refresh

    // Initialize the OAuth client
    $oauthClient = new GenericProvider([
        'clientId'                => config('msgraph.clientId'),
        'clientSecret'            => config('msgraph.clientSecret'),
        'redirectUri'             => config('msgraph.redirectUri'),
        'urlAuthorize'            => config('msgraph.urlAuthorize'),
        'urlAccessToken'          => config('msgraph.urlAccessToken'),
        'urlResourceOwnerDetails' => config('msgraph.urlResourceOwnerDetails'),
        'scopes'                  => config('msgraph.scopes')
    ]);

    $newToken = $oauthClient->getAccessToken('refresh_token', ['refresh_token' => $token->refresh_token]);

    return $newToken->getToken();
}
```

This example is taken from a Laravel implementation but illustrates the idea.

Comment: You completely missed the point!  The complaint was not knowing when the REFRESH TOKEN expires.  Your code is simply dealing with the token expiration not the refresh token.  When the refresh token expires the getAccessToken will fail.  It can be useful to know that this will occur in a process where the ability to acquire a new refresh token may not be possible or desired (such as for security)